# Smoothly make a number approach zero

Tags: animation, math

I have a floating point value X which is animated. When in rest it's at zero, but at times an outside source may change it to somewhere between -1 and 1.

If that happens I want it to go smoothly back to 0. I currently do something like

```
addToXspeed(-x * FACTOR);

// below is out of my control
function addToXspeed(bla) {
 xspeed += bla;
 x += xspeed;
}
```

every step in the animation, but that only causes X to oscillate. I want it to rest on 0 however.

(I've explained the problem in abstracts. The specific thing I'm trying to do is make a jumping game character balance himself upright in the air by applying rotational force)

Comment: FACTOR should be between 0 and 1.

Comment: What type is `x`? Floating point numbers might not be accurate enough anyway. By the way, your code is `x=x-x*f`, which is the same as `x=(1-f)x`. This is a little backwards definition of `Factor`.

Comment: In context, can you program? Do you have variables (if so, to can tell when the value is changed)? Should `0.5` take half the time than `1` to reach zero, or even time?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you can not assign values directly to Xspeed? Can you read the value of Xspeed?

Comment: @AB: that's correct, and I can read its value. that's how I came to my solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing the question oftens results in realising the answer.

```
targetxspeed = -x * FACTOR;
addToXspeed(targetxspeed - xspeed);

// below is out of my control
function addToXspeed(bla) {
 xspeed += bla;
 x += xspeed;
}
```

So simple too

Answer (score 2):

Interesting problem.
What you are asking for is the stabilization of the following discrete-time linear system:

```
|     x(t+1)| = | 1   dt | |     x(t)|  +  | 0 | u(t)
|xspeed(t+1)|   | 0    1 | |xspeed(t)|     | 1 |
```

where `dt` is the sampling time and `u(t)` is the quantity you `addToXspeed()`. (Further, the system is subject to random disturbances on the first variable `x`, which I don't show in the equation above.) Now if you "set the control input equal to a linear feedback of the state", i.e.

```
u(t) = [a  b] |     x(t)| = a*x(t) + b*xspeed(t)
              |xspeed(t)|
```

then the "closed-loop" system becomes

```
|     x(t+1)| = | 1   dt  | |     x(t)|
|xspeed(t+1)|   | a   b+1 | |xspeed(t)|
```

Now, in order to obtain "asymptotic stability" of the system, we stipulate that the eigenvalues of the closed-loop matrix are placed "inside the complex unit circle", and we do this by tuning `a` and `b`. We place the eigenvalues, say, at 0.5.
Therefore the characteristic polynomial of the closed-loop matrix, which is

```
(s - 1)(s - (b+1)) - a*dt = s^2 -(2+b)*s + (b+1-a*dt)
```

should equal

```
(s - 0.5)^2 = s^2 - s + 0.25
```

This is easily attained if we choose

```
b = -1    a = -0.25/dt
```

or

```
u(t) = a*x(t) + b*xspeed(t) = -(0.25/dt)*x(t) - xspeed(t)
addToXspeed(u(t))
```

which is more or less what appears in your own answer

```
targetxspeed = -x * FACTOR;
addToXspeed(targetxspeed - xspeed);
```

where, if we are asked to place the eigenvalues at 0.5, we should set `FACTOR = (0.25/dt)`.

Comment: Hihi, sorry I couldn't resist. Besides, I think that if you choose FACTOR too big you may actually _destabilize_ the system, i.e. the particle gets farther and farther from zero. And I also think that the oscillatory behavior of his previous policy can be explained in this framework...

Comment: Wow...extensive. Next time I have something like this but more complex I'll go back and read this answer in depth :)

Answer (score 1):

x = x*FACTOR

This should do the trick when factor is between 0 and 1.

The lower the factor the quicker you'll go to 0.

Comment: I think that'll work, but I have the following problem: I can't really assign x, I can only call a function addToX(bla). Working on transforming the statement...

Comment: Actually I wrongly wrote down what happens. I edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you define a fixed step to be decremented from `x`?

You just have to be sure to make it small enough so that the said person doesn't seem to be traveling at small bursts at a time, but not small enough that she doesn't move at a perceived rate.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to scale it but can only add, then you have to figure out which value to add in order to get the desired scaling:

Let's say `x = 0.543`, and we want to cause it to rapidly go towards 0, i.e. by dropping it by 95%.

We want to do:

```
scaled_x = x * (1.0 - 0.95);
```

This would leave x at 0.543 * 0.05, or `0.02715`. The difference between this value and the original is then what you need to add to get this value:

```
delta = scaled_x - x;
```

This would make delta equal `-0,51585`, which is what you need to add to simulate a scaling by 5%.